# mysqlにERROR 1045でログインできない

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

## 動作環境

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

## 本題

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

にてローカル上のmysqlへのログインを試みると、

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

というエラーが出てログインすることができません。

mysqlのセーフモードでの起動も試みましたが失敗に終わりました。

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mysql
~
$ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 7461
~
$ 2020-05-09T09:53:03.108631Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 144: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
2020-05-09T09:53:03.112185Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 144: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

管理者権限で実行しても結果は失敗でした。

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 7641
~
$ 2020-05-09T09:54:12.224601Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2020-05-09T09:54:12.226560Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

mysqlをpurgeしてからの再インストールも試しましたが、結果は同じでした。

```
sudo apt purge mysql*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

mysqlへのログイン方法を教えて下さい。

## 追記

mysqldディレクトリを作成することで、エラー1045は出なくなりました。

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

しかし代わりにエラー2002が出現するようになりました。

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

質問のエラー対象が変わってしまったため、新たに質問を作成しました。
↓
[mysqlにERROR 2002でログインできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66460/mysql%e3%81%aberror-2002%e3%81%a7%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` に `debian-sys-maint` ユーザとそのパスワードが書かれています。一旦、`debian-sys-maint` ユーザでログインして root のパスワードを変更すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ログインしようとするとエラーが発生してしまいます。
mysql -u debian-sys-maint
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: mysqld をリスタートする(`sudo systemctl restart mysql`)と socket ファイル(`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`)が作成されます。お試し下さい。

Comment: 実行してみましたが、エラー内容に変化はありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqldディレクトリを作成することで、エラー1045は出なくなりました。

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

しかし代わりにエラー2002が出現するようになりました。

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

質問のエラー対象が変わってしまったため、新たに質問を作成しました。
↓
[mysqlにERROR 2002でログインできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66460/mysql%e3%81%aberror-2002%e3%81%a7%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)