# mysqlにERROR 2002でログインできない

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

## 動作環境

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

## 本題

mysqlへのログインを試みているのですが、エラー2002のためログインできません。

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

ソケットの削除を行いましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

```
$ sudo rm -f /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
$ sudo rm -f /tmp/mysql.sock
$ sudo systemctl restart mysql
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

## 追記情報

### mysqlのリスタート実行時の動作

mysqlのリスタートを行おうとした際、以下の`mysql.server`コマンドが見つかりません。

```
$ mysql.server restart
mysql.server: command not found
```

この方法でmysqlのリスタートを行おうとすると失敗します。

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

### systemctl status mysql.service実行結果

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sat 2020-05-09 20:47:01 JST; 31s ago
    Process: 17567 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 17575 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 9177)
     Memory: 239.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─17575 /usr/sbin/mysqld

 5月 09 20:47:01 ******* systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

Comment: `systemctl status mysql.service` の実行結果(表示内容)を追記して貰えますか？

Comment: @metropolis systemctl status mysql.service実行結果を質問内に追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一度mysqlを削除して再インストールすることでエラーを解消しました。
エラーの原因については不明のままです。